# DOS batch file to enter commands in proprietary java app and receive feedback?

Tags: java, command, dos, batch-file

I'm working on a project in which I'd like to be able to turn lights on and off in the Duke Smart Home via a high frequency chirp.  The lighting system is called Clipsal Square-D and the program that gives a user access to the lighting controls is called CGate.  I was planning on doing some signal processing in Matlab, then create a batch file from Matlab to interact with Cgate.  Cgate is a proprietary Java app that, if run from a DOS command line, opens up another window that physically looks like the DOS command prompt.  I have a batch file that can check to see if Cgate is running and if not, open it.

But what I can't figure out how to do is actually run commands in the Cgate program from the batch file and likewise, take the response from Cgate.  An example of such a command is "noop," which should return "200 OK."

Any help would be much appreciated!  Thank you very much in advance :)

(here's my existing batch file by the way)

```
@ECHO off

goto checkIfOpen

:checkIfOpen

REM pv finds all open processes and puts it in result.txt
%SystemRoot%\pv\pv.exe
%SystemRoot%\pv\pv.exe > result.txt

REM if result has the word notepad in it then notepad is running
REM if not then it opens notepad
FIND "notepad.exe" result.txt
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 START %SystemRoot%\system32\Clipsal\C-Gate2\cgate.exe

goto end

:end
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do this on Windows, but on UNIX, there is a program called [expect](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/expect/) that is designed for such a task. If you install [Cygwin](http://cygwin.com/), you should be able to use the expect utility on Windows.

Comment: I downloaded expect but I can't understand how to incorporate it into a batch file - do you have any more tips on syntax and the like?

Comment: I looked more into things and found out that "cygwin's Expect works fine under Cygwin as long as what you're expect'ing upon is a cygwin application. It does not work with normal/native Win32 console applications."  So I tried using ActiveState's version but am stumped.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `start cgate.exe`, which will cause cgate.exe to be launched in a new window. First off, you probably want to run cgate in the same window, which means you should drop the `start`.

Secondly, you can use shell redirection to pass commands to the STDIN of `cgate` from a text file, like so:

```
cgate.exe < commands.txt
```

This will *probably* work, but it might not, depending on how cgate.exe is actually expected to receive its data.

If you want to have two-way communication, where you send in data, get the response, then send in more data depending on what the response was, you'll have to use something other than a batch file. Most scripting languages (perl, python) could be used for this purpose, or C or anything else.